# How to use preview version of office-js in outlook addin

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

I need to fetch some context objects which are available only in preview version of office-js, like "Recurrence" and others. 
I have updated office-js in my html to [https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js][1]

but still getting null in response to `Office.context.mailbox.item.recurrence.getAsync`

Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

APIs that are in preview are not guaranteed to be implemented in all clients. These APIs will be released from preview as a requirement set when they are available in all clients.

> **Note:** This [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/preview/index?product=outlook&version=preview) is for a preview requirement set. This requirement set is not fully implemented yet, and clients will not accurately report support for it. You should not specify this requirement set in your add-in manifest. Methods and properties that are introduced in this requirement set should be individually tested for availability before using them.

Comment: Can you please help us, as we want to use Recurrence appointment inside our addin but when we are trying to use latest preview version we are getting null even on recurrence appointment.
Minimum version we are using for Manifest is 1.1 
Can you please guide us how we can do it so that we can use recurrence object in our addin using latest  beta office.js
https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js

we got some impression that Microsoft will release beta version of office.js at the end of year, so we were trying to implement it and will release our addin next year

Comment: Using the beta version of Office.js will not guarantee that the API will work in a given client. There are client side changes required that may not be available. Which client are you targeting for your add-in currently?

Comment: Currently we are targeting Web client and Windows native outlook app. Suggest changes we need to do for this.

Comment: As per the above shared document I found a 404 on https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/preview/tutorial-api-requirement-setsl . No document found for the same. Please help us out.

Comment: See [this](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets) link. We will work to update our documentation.

Comment: We have tried with 1.6 as minversion in requirement set but still the same result. Is there any other minversion to define for beta/preview.

Comment: There is no way to specify the minimum API version for preview.

Comment: So according to this there is no way we can use preview features even inside our environment.

Comment: At the time of this comment, the Recurrence APIs are supported in Outlook 2016 (Click to Run). Please be sure to update to the latest version. Support for Outlook on the Web is coming soon.

Comment: Till when we can expect this feature to go in GA?

Comment: Hi Vikash, we don't have a timeline to share at the moment of when the API will hit GA, but this is something we are actively working on.

Comment: It would appear that `Office.context.mailbox.item.recurrence.getAsync` no longer works for Office 2016, at the time of this comment.